# How to disable default AWS Lambda logging?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda unfortunately logs rather a log of the following lines:

```
START RequestId: 9becdd00-2f91-4841-97d7-d1b8eddbcd5c Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 9becdd00-2f91-4841-97d7-d1b8eddbcd5c
REPORT RequestId: 9becdd00-2f91-4841-97d7-d1b8eddbcd5c  Duration: 5709.73 ms    Billed Duration: 5710 ms    Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 106 MB Init Duration: 556.64 ms
```

Is there a way to disable these without affecting the underlying logging code or at least lower the logging levels? We have quite a few Lambdas and they're very noisy.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have to **remove permissions** `logs:CreateLogGroup`, `logs:CreateLogStream` and `logs:PutLogEvents` from your lambda execution role.

Comment: No because we still want logs from the Lambda, just not these ones

"Is there a way to disable these without affecting the underlying logging code or at least lower the logging levels?"

Comment: @rACkle There is no other way. Either you disable everything, or nothing.

Comment: An unfortunate end to this query. Thanks!

Comment: This will disable other logs, not a proper solution

Comment: @IlyaLibin If you know the "proper" solution, why not make an answer with it?

Comment: I agree with the others, this is not answering the question

Comment: @omriman12 Please feel free to provide the answer then.

Comment: @Marchin The answer in as you mentioned in your comment - it's not possible, I advise you update your answer

Comment: @Marcin, I don't know, I'm looking for one, but your's doesn't seem to solve it.